# Show that $A_f$ is measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak M,\mu)$ be space with \sigma finite measure and let $f$ be positive measurable function on $X.$ If $\lambda=\mu\times m$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure, show that $A_f=\{(x,t):x\in X,0\leq t \leq f(x)\}$ is measurable set in $X\times \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Can you prove it if $f$ is simple?

Comment: Yes, that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

First, suppose $f$ is simple, so that $f(x)=\sum_1^N a_n \chi _{E_N}(x)$, where each $E_n \subset X$ is measurable. Then $A_f= \bigcup_n E_n \times [0,a_n]$ is measurable.

Now, in general, we can choose a sequence of simple functions $\phi_k \uparrow f$.  Then each $A_{\phi_k}$ is measurable and $A_f = \bigcup_k A_{\phi_k}$, proving the result.

Comment: Nice, I understand. Thanks.